# Is there a word for someone who is biased, or prejudiced against, or who harbors contempt for poor people?

Tags: word-request

What is a good word to describe someone who is like racist or class-ist or homophobic, but instead whom they don't like is don't like poor people?

I'd like a word that gets the point across with enough truth to be noticable, yet not necessarily be viewed as an attack.

Answer (score 3):

The word you may be looking for is **snob**.

Someone who is a **snob**, ***thinks*** they are better than others (whether or not they actually are) and can be based on class divisions.

> Ever since he bought that fancy new car, he's been a **snob** about his friends' old cars.

There are intellectual snobs, social snobs, economic snobs, the list goes on...

Another possible word is **elitist**.

> His **elitist** views of an upper class leaves no room for social mobility.

but tends to be more class related.

A phrase which gets used to separate those who **worship profits at any cost** is

> **capitalist pig**

and refers to persons who look to enrich themselves at the expense of the (relatively) less advantaged, they usually have a disdain (or no time) for those with less money than themselves. Think *The Great Gatsby* or *The Wolf of Wall Street*. Capitalists, especially Darwinian Capitalists, will tend to believe that their success is due to superiority in ability and those with less are of a lesser ability.  This should not be confused with the Calvinist belief that earthly success is a sign of God's grace.

Comment: This is a tough one, because you can be an elitist or snob without having contempt for poor people. For example, if students in the Engineering program refer to another program as Arts & Crafts instead of Arts & Sciences, they're being elitist snobs but that doesn't mean they're looking down on poor folks. It seems like there is a word or phrase out there, but I haven't been able to think of it. Snob is closer than elitist I think.

Comment: I agree with @Colleen - _snob_ can work, but it needs to have enough context around it to work.

Comment: My husband suggested [bourgeoisie](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bourgeoisie), which doesn't directly capture the meaning, but does have the connotation of being oppressive to the "working class". On the other hand, when it's used in a derogatory way, it's usually about folks acting like they are in a higher social class than they are - see [bougie in the urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bougie). What do you think @J.R.?

Answer (score 1):

Aporophobia

Aporophobia is a neologism created by the renowned Spanish philosopher Adela Cortina to describe “rejection of the poor”. It articulates a wide range of social phenomena that shapes the interaction between the poor and the non-poor, such as aversion, antipathy, contempt, disgust, disregard, fear and hate
[https://www.iqs.edu/en/aporophobia#:~:text=Aporophobia%20is%20a%20neologism%20created,%2C%20disregard%2C%20fear%20and%20hate](https://www.iqs.edu/en/aporophobia#:%7E:text=Aporophobia%20is%20a%20neologism%20created,%2C%20disregard%2C%20fear%20and%20hate).

Answer (score 0):

There is the adjective [*Snooty*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+snooty)

A snooty person is one who specifically dislikes persons that they consider to be inferior - especially of lower class.
It derives from the habit of looking down their nose (their snout) when face to face with such an inferior person.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question today and this is all I could find.

aporophobia:

(rare) A strong antipathy, aversion or hatred toward poverty or poor people.